# Discord.py music bot, using a text file to save volume integer but I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make a Discord.py bot. While modifying some of the base code for the music portion to store the volume in a text file(so it's consistent everytime it plays a new song) and I ran into some problems.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here's my code for the relevant portion:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def volume(self, ctx, value: int):
        """Sets the volume of the currently playing song."""

        state = self.get_voice_state(ctx.message.server)
        with open(r'E:\PythonProjects\WeebBot\textfiles\volumefile.txt', 'r+') as volumefile:
            open(r'E:\PythonProjects\WeebBot\textfiles\volumefile.txt', 'w')
            volumefile.write(str(value))
            if state.is_playing():
                read_data = volumefile.read()
                player = state.player
                player.volume = int(read_data.rstrip('\n')) / 100
                await self.bot.say('Set the volume to {:.0%}'.format(player.volume))
        volumefile.close()
```

I've tried using floats (player.volume uses 0.1 to 2.0 as values for volume from 1% to 200%) and I think I also delete any \n chars that might show up at the end of the file. I'm only reading ints all bunched up so I don't believe I need to do anything else?

Comment: Why are you opening the same file twice? The second open, in write mode, destroys the info in the file.

Comment: I was told using the second open with only write access would wipe it, so I could then write on it the value I want with volumefile.write(str(value))

Comment: Exactly wipe it, ie destroy the contents before you've read them!! And place's the file pointer after what you've written so that when the read statement is executed it returns None because it is trying to read beyond the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to read the value from the file, since the content of the text file is always `value`.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
async def volume(self, ctx, value: int):
    """Sets the volume of the currently playing song."""

    state = self.get_voice_state(ctx.message.server)
    with open(r'E:\PythonProjects\WeebBot\textfiles\volumefile.txt', 'w') as volumefile:
        volumefile.write(str(value))
    if state.is_playing():
        player = state.player
        player.volume = value / 100
        await self.bot.say('Set the volume to {:.0%}'.format(player.volume))
```

If you still want to read from the file, you need to re-open the file with `r` permission.

Comment: Ok so if I'm following this correctly, we open the file and immediately write the value passed by the def volume? I get what you're doing I think, but is there any reason why my original version was not giving me an int?

EDIT: Not string, I meant an int.

Comment: @Bernas The content you wrote to the file doesn't get saved until you closes or flushes the file (when the with statement ends), therefore there was nothing to read, thus your error.